# Crashlytics is working for develop environment and not for prod in iOS. What may be the reason?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

Crashlytics is working for develop environment and not for prod iOS. What may be the reason?

Respective info.plist files are added

Added all the run script and what might be the issue ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.